# matplotlib figure screen menu changed?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, matlab-figure, figure

Some time ago (maybe 1 month ago), when I was making a plot of several files into one graph, the window with the plot results had a button that allowed me to select one or more plots to be displayed in the same graph
[image]

now i am trying to do the same thing.
I'm plotting a directory with n files in the same graph but the plot.show () results window no longer has the button that allowed me to decide which plots to display at the same time

[image]

i'm using the same imports: pandas, matplotlib, numpy, os, tkinter

someone know how to change this toolbar into figure window?

(sorry for my english, if it is unclear I try to explain myself better)

Comment: Not generally reproducible with matplotlib 3.3.3. I suggest you add information about system specifications (OS, backend, matplotlib, Python versions). Is the error the same for [different backends](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend)? Did you change anything a month ago?

Comment: same OS, no backend, same python version. In this script i'm using TkAgg only for plot inside a tkinter canvas (with a check button it will display it into a canvas in the UI or as a classic plt.show() figure window, without a specific backend, just like 1 month ago)